# Sending mutiple file using socket and c under ubuntu 22

Tags: c, linux, sockets, client-server

So  I'm trying  to send more than a file  from my server side to the client  .I have already completed the  task of  sending  one file with its  size. To explain more  the  name of the file is passed as  argument to the client then send to the  server to check if there is  a file with this name in the shared folder by the server, if yes then the  server sends the file to the client.
My idea was  send the number of files to be sent  to the client  then do the same  stuff I do for one single file in for loop  but the  cold  crush I don't now  why.

And I also try to connect  using  wifi in 2 different PC but  the  code  does it work correctly, I  test it  before using ethernet cable and all go ok
Can any one help me please?

this link to the project folder  :

https://github.com/amaraoussama94/Server_Client-C-app

i try  some  video youtube and some other  solution but it crush
i expect to have some idea , or code to boost me
Snap of project :

server :

```
    #include <arpa/inet.h> // inet_addr()/
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <netdb.h>
    #include <netinet/in.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>//system
    #include <string.h>
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <unistd.h> // read(), write(), close()
    #include <errno.h>
    #include "Const.h"
    #include "arg_test.h"
    #include <time.h>//get time and date for log file 
    #include <string.h>//
    
    

    //void* SendFileToClient(int *arg)
    void SendFileToClient(int *ptr_connfd,char * fname ,struct sockaddr_in cli )
    {
        //int connfd=(int)*arg;
        printf("[i]Connection accepted and id: %d\n",*ptr_connfd);
        printf("[i]Connected to Clent: %s:%d\n",inet_ntoa(cli.sin_addr),ntohs(cli.sin_port));
        write(*ptr_connfd, fname,256);
    
        FILE *fp = fopen(fname,"rb");
        if(fp==NULL)
        {
            printf("\033[0;31m");
            printf("[-]File for transfer  open error\n");
            printf("\033[0m");
            exit(1);   
        }   
        /*******************************************/
        fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
      
        // calculating the size of the file
        long int res = ftell(fp);
        //conver to char to send it 
        char size[10];
        sprintf(size, "%f", (res/1024.0) );
        //send file size to  the client 
        write(*ptr_connfd, size, sizeof(size));
        printf("[i]size of the file to transfer is  %f Kb\n",(res/1024.0));
        fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
        /******************************************/
            /* Read data from file and send it */
        while(1)
        {
            /* First read file in chunks of 256 bytes */
            unsigned char buff[1024]={0};
            int nread = fread(buff,1,1024,fp);
            //printf("Bytes read %d \n", nread);        
    
            /* If read was success, send data. */
            if(nread > 0)
            {
                //printf("Sending \n");
                write(*ptr_connfd, buff, nread);
            }
            if (nread < 1024)
            {
                if (feof(fp))
                {
    
                   // printf("End of file\n");
                    printf("\033[0;32m");
                    printf("[+]File transfer completed for id: %d\n",*ptr_connfd);
                    printf("\033[0m");
                }
                if (ferror(fp))
                {   
                    printf("\033[0;31m");
                    printf("[-]Error reading file for  transfer \n");
                    printf("\033[0m");
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        printf("\033[0;32m");
        printf("[+]Closing Connection for id: %d\n",*ptr_connfd);
        printf("\033[0;31m");
        close(*ptr_connfd);
        //shutdown(*ptr_connfd,SHUT_WR);
        sleep(2);
    }
    

    // Function designed for chat between client and server.
    int share_msg(int* ptr_connfd,char **argv ,struct sockaddr_in cli,int *ptr_change )
    {
        FILE  *filePointer,*filePointerTransfer ;
    
        char cmd [100]="./script.sh  ";
        char buff[MAX];
        char string[MAX];
        int Exist =0   ;
        int  j =0;
    
        int err ;
        pthread_t tid; 
        // bzero :Set N bytes of pointer to 0.   
        bzero(buff, MAX);//or you can use memset (&buff,'\0',sizeof(buff))
    
        // read the message from client and copy it in buffer
        read(*ptr_connfd, buff, sizeof(buff));
        // print buffer which contains the client contents
        
        if (strncmp("bash_list", buff, 9) == 0) 
        {   printf("[i]The client wants information about shared folder\n ");
            //| awk  '{print $1 " " $11 }'  " " : field are sparate with space , $1 et $ 11 print colom1 and 11
            //chdir(argv[4]);// change the path 
            strcat(cmd,argv[4]);
            //int status = system("ls -al|awk '{print $1 " " $11}' > cmdoutput" ); 
            int status = system(cmd); 
            //open file 
            filePointer = fopen("stdout.txt", "r");
            //ste the psotion of the  pointer at the bening of the file
            if (filePointer == NULL)
                {
                    printf("\033[0;31m");
                    printf("[-]Error can t find list of file to share \n");
                    printf("\033[0m");
                    bzero(buff,sizeof(buff));
                    strcat(buff,"ERRORFILE1");
                    write(*ptr_connfd, buff, sizeof(buff));
                    exit(1);
                }
            fseek(filePointer, 0, SEEK_SET);
            while(fgets(buff, MAX, filePointer)) 
            {   
            
                //   send that buffer to clients
                
                if (strncmp(buff ,".",1)==0 ||  strncmp(buff ,"..",2)==0  ||  strncmp(buff ,"/",1)==0)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                
                write(*ptr_connfd, buff, sizeof(buff));
                
            }
    
            bzero(buff, MAX);
            for(int j =0 ;j<sizeof(buff);j++)
            {
                buff[j] =  '#';
            }
            //send to client                    
            write(*ptr_connfd, buff, sizeof(buff));
            //file 
            fclose(filePointer);
    
            return 1;
        }
        else if (strcmp("bash_Transf", buff) == 0) 
        {
            int num_file ; 
            //get numlber of  file to send 
            bzero(buff, MAX);
            read(*ptr_connfd, buff, sizeof(buff));
            sscanf(buff,"%d",&num_file);
            printf("[i] the  number of file to send to the client is %d\n",num_file);
            //get file name 
            bzero(buff, MAX);
            read(*ptr_connfd, buff, sizeof(buff));
            printf("the file name is %s \n",buff);
            /*********************************************///must change dir if it run 2nd it  crush 
            char path[100] ;
            //get the current  dir path  
            
            if (*ptr_change)
            {
                getcwd(path, sizeof(path)) ;
            }
            *ptr_change =0 ;
            int dir_test = chdir(path);
            //printf(" hello dir_test =%d and path=%s\n",dir_test,path);
            //system("pwd");//test to check  dir path
            /********************************************/
            filePointer = fopen("stdout.txt", "r");
            if (filePointer == NULL)
            {
                printf("\033[0;31m");
                printf("[-]Error can t find list of file to share \n");
                printf("\033[0m");
                exit(1);
            }
            //get iof the file name  existt or no in the shared folder 
            while (  fgets( string ,MAX, filePointer) )// fscanf(filePointer,"%s", string) == 1
            {
                //lets take out the \n  introduce by fgets 
                string[strcspn(string,"\n")]= 0;
                
                if (strcmp(string,buff)==0)
                {
                    Exist = 1;
                    break;
                }   
            }
            if (Exist)
            {   
                fclose(filePointer);
                //transfer file here 
                chdir(argv[4]);// change the path 
                printf( "[i]the file for transfer  name is = %s \n",buff);
    
                SendFileToClient(ptr_connfd,buff ,cli );
                //create thread  for sending the file to the client 
                /*err = pthread_create(&tid, NULL, &SendFileToClient, ptr_connfd);
                if (err != 0)
                    printf("\ncan't create thread :[%s]", strerror(err));*/
                 
            }
            else
            {
                
                bzero(buff, sizeof(buff));
                strcat(buff,"file_error");
                write(*ptr_connfd, buff, sizeof(buff));
                bzero(buff, sizeof(buff));
                printf("\033[0;31m");
                printf("[-] Client try to get file that doesn't exist in the  shared folder \n");
                printf("\033[0m");
            }
    
            // si il n y a  aucun paramatere passe au clien ni t ni
            // list le  server se ferme  par  return 1 and close the while loop
            return 1;
        }
        else 
            return 0;
        
    } 

    void create_scoket(int * sockfd)
    {
        *sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);// AF_INET :IPV4  , SOCK_STREAM:TCP
        if (sockfd < 0) 
        {
            printf("\033[0;31m");
            perror("[-]socket creation failed...\n");
            printf("\033[0m");
            exit(1);
        }
        else
        {   
            printf("\033[0;32m");
            printf("[+]Socket successfully created..\n");
            printf("\033[0m");
        }
        
    }


    
    void socket_bind(struct sockaddr_in *servaddr ,int * sockfd)
    {
        
        // Binding newly created socket to given IP and verification
        if ((bind(*sockfd, (SA*)servaddr, sizeof(*servaddr))) < 0) 
        {
            printf("\033[0;31m");
            perror("[-]socket bind failed...\n");
            printf("\033[0m");
            exit(1);
        }
        else
        {   
            printf("\033[0;32m");
            printf("[+]Socket successfully binded..\n");
            printf("\033[0m");
        }
    }
    

    void socket_listening (int *sockfd)
    {
        if ((listen(*sockfd, LISTENQ)) != 0) //5 connection requests will be queued before further requests are refused.
        {
            printf("\033[0;31m");
            printf("[-]Listen failed...\n");
            printf("\033[0m");
            exit(1);
        }
        else
        {   
            printf("\033[0;32m");
            printf("[+]Server listening..\n");
            printf("\033[0m");
        }
    }

    
    void socket_accept (int *connfd , int* sockfd ,struct sockaddr_in*cli , int *len)
    {
        *connfd = accept(*sockfd, (SA*)cli, len);
                
            if (connfd < 0) 
            {
                printf("\033[0;31m");
                perror("[-]server accept failed...\n");
                printf("\033[0m");
                exit(1);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("\033[0;32m");
                printf("[+]server accept the client...\n");
                printf("\033[0m");
            }
    }
    // Driver function 
  
    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
        //for socket
        int sockfd, connfd, len;
        int *ptr_sockfd ,*ptr_connfd , *ptr_len;
        struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cli;
        struct sockaddr_in *ptr_servaddr , *ptr_cli;
        
        int change =1 ; //for transfer 
        int *ptr_change =&change;
        check_arg_server(argc,argv);
        // socket create and verification
        ptr_sockfd = &sockfd;
        create_scoket(ptr_sockfd);
        //initialize to zeo 
        // bzero :Set N bytes of pointer to 0.  
        bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));//or you can use memset (&servaddr,'\0', sizeof(servaddr))
    
        // assign IP, PORT
        servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr =htonl(INADDR_ANY);// Address to accept any incoming messages.   
        servaddr.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[2]));//htons :Functions to convert between host and network byte order
        //binding
        ptr_servaddr = &servaddr;
        socket_bind(ptr_servaddr ,ptr_sockfd);
    
        // Now server is ready to listen and verification
        socket_listening (ptr_sockfd);
    
        //chek for ctr+z as input to stope server   
        while (1)
        {
            
            len = sizeof(cli);
            //printf("hello ok \n");
            // Accept the data packet from client and verification
            ptr_connfd = &connfd;
            ptr_len = &len;
            ptr_cli= &cli ;
            socket_accept (ptr_connfd , ptr_sockfd , ptr_cli , ptr_len);
     
            //temp sol to stop server 
            int b = share_msg(ptr_connfd,argv,cli,ptr_change);
            if (!b)
            {
                close(connfd);
                break;
            }
            close(connfd);
            sleep(1);   
            
        }
        // After chatting close the socket
        close(sockfd);
        printf("[i] Server will Shutdown  \n");
        return 0;   
    }
```

client :

```
    #include <arpa/inet.h> // inet_addr()/
    #include <netdb.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <strings.h> // bzero()
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <unistd.h> // read(), write(), close()
    #include "Const.h"
    #include "arg_test.h"
    // for mkdir function 
    #include <sys/stat.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    const int PROG_BAR_LENGTH =30 ;//30 caractere

    
  
    
    
    
    void update_bar(float  percent_done  )
    {    
        int num_car =(int) percent_done * PROG_BAR_LENGTH  / 100 ;//number  of caractere to print 
        printf(" \r[");
        for(int i =0;i<num_car;i++)
        {
            printf("\033[0;32m"); //Set the text to the color Green
            printf("■");
        }
        for(int i =0;i<(PROG_BAR_LENGTH -num_car);i++) //unfinish part of  progress bar 
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        if((int)percent_done > 100)
        {
            percent_done =100 ;
        }
        printf("\033[0m"); //Resets the text to default color
        printf("] %d%% Done.",(int)percent_done );
       // fflush(stdout);//print all to the  screen  
    }
    
    
    
 
     
    

    
    void share_msg(int *sockfd,char ** argv, int argc)
    {
        char buff[MAX]="bash";
        char msg[MAX];
        
        FILE *filetransferPointer;
        int n , bytesReceived = 0 ;
    
        if  (strcmp("--list", argv[5]) == 0)
        {
            strcat(buff,"_list");
        }
        if (strcmp("-T", argv[5]) == 0) 
        {
            strcat(buff,"_Transf");
        }
        //send to  server
        write(*sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff));
        bzero(buff, sizeof(buff));
        if  (strcmp("--list", argv[5]) == 0)
        {
            //read receive msg from server
            read(*sockfd, msg, sizeof(msg));
            read(*sockfd, msg, sizeof(msg));
            if(!strcmp(msg,"ERRORFILE1"))
            {
                printf("[-] Error server can t list file \n ");
                exit(1);
            }
            printf("[i]This is the list of file and  folder shared by the server : \n These are the directories  : \n" );
            while(1)
            {
                read(*sockfd, msg, sizeof(msg));
                
                if(!strncmp(msg, "#", 1) )
                {
                    break;
    
                }
                printf("%s \n ",msg);
            } 
        }
        else if (strcmp("-T", argv[5]) == 0) 
        {
            //get number of file to receive from server 
            int num_file = argc-6;
            bzero(msg, sizeof(msg));
            sprintf(msg,"%d",num_file);
            write(*sockfd, msg, sizeof(msg));
            //printf ("num = %s\n",msg);
            //send file name to server 
            bzero(msg, sizeof(msg));
            strcat(msg,argv[6]);
            printf(" the  buff is = %s",msg);
            write(*sockfd, msg, sizeof(msg));
            //check if the file name exist or no
            bzero(msg, sizeof(msg));
            read(*sockfd, msg, sizeof(msg));
            if (strcmp(msg,"file_error")==0)
            {   printf("\033[0;31m");
                printf("[-]Please try  again ,maybe try --list first then try again ,or maybe no file has this name \n" );
                printf("\033[0m");
                exit(1);
            }   
    
            //get the  file 
            char* dirname = "transfer";
            mkdir(dirname,0755);
            //system("mkdir transfer");
            chdir("transfer");
            //system("cd test/");
            //system("pwd");
            filetransferPointer = fopen(argv[6] , "ab");
            if (filetransferPointer == NULL)
            {
                printf("\033[0;31m");
                printf("[-]Error  can t  create file for transfer  \n");
                printf("\033[0m");
                exit(-1);
            }
            /**********************************************/
            char size[10];
            long double size_file =0;
            read(*sockfd, size, sizeof(size));
            //convert data to  long double
            sscanf(size, "%Lf", &size_file);
            printf("[i]Size of the file %Lf Kb \n",size_file);
            /*************************************************/
            
            /* Receive data in chunks of 256 bytes */
            long double sz=0;
            long double * ptr_sz =&sz;
            while((bytesReceived = read(*sockfd, msg, 1024)) > 0)
            { 
                //sz++;
                //gotoxy(0,4);
                //printf(" \r Received: %LF Mb \t \t \t",(sz/1024)); //LF for long double
                //fflush(stdout);
                // recvBuff[n] = 0;
                /******************************************************/
                  double percent_done;
                //long double  batch_size =1/1024 ;//Mb
                percent_done += 100/ size_file ; //;(batch_size/size_file)*100
                //printf(" the file  size is %Lf the percent_done = %lf  and in in = %d \n",size_file,percent_done,(int)percent_done);
                update_bar(percent_done);
                fflush(stdout);
                fwrite(msg, 1,bytesReceived,filetransferPointer);
                usleep(20000);//sleep for 20ms
                //printf("%s \n", recvBuff);
            }
            printf("\n");
    
            if(bytesReceived < 0)
            {
                printf("[-]Error  can t  create file %s to recive it  \n",argv[6]);
            }
            fclose(filetransferPointer);
            printf("[i] file transmission %s is done you can check transfer folder   \n",argv[6]);
    
        }
                
    }
    

    void create_scoket(int * sockfd)
    {
        *sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);// AF_INET :IPV4  , SOCK_STREAM:TCP
        if (sockfd < 0) 
        {
            printf("\033[0;31m");
            perror("[-]socket creation failed...\n");
            printf("\033[0;31m");
            exit(1);
        }
        else
        {   printf("\033[0;32m");
            printf("[+]Socket successfully created..\n"); 
            printf("\033[0m");
        }
        
    }
    
    

    
    void socket_connect(struct sockaddr_in *servaddr ,int * sockfd)
    {
        
        if (connect(*sockfd, (SA*)servaddr, sizeof(*servaddr)) <0) 
        {
            printf("\033[0;31m");
            perror("[-]connection with the server failed...\n");
            printf("\033[0m");
            exit(1);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\033[0;32m");
            printf("[+]connected to the server..\n");
            printf("\033[0m");
        }
    
    }
    
    
    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
        int sockfd, connfd;
        int *ptr_sockfd;
        struct sockaddr_in servaddr, client_addr;
        struct sockaddr_in *ptr_servaddr;
    
        //check argument 
        check_arg_client(argc,argv);
        
        // socket create and verification
        ptr_sockfd= &sockfd;
         create_scoket(ptr_sockfd);
            //initialize to zeo 
            // bzero :Set N bytes of pointer to 0.  
        bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));//or you can use memset (&servaddr,'\0', sizeof(servaddr))
        
        // assign IP, PORT
        servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[2]);// the adress of the serveur 
        servaddr.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[4]));  //htons :Functions to convert between host and network byte order
        // connect the client socket to server socket
        ptr_servaddr = &servaddr ;
        socket_connect(ptr_servaddr ,ptr_sockfd);
     
        // run the lisst or transfer  option 
        if( argc > 5)
        {
            share_msg(ptr_sockfd,argv, argc);
        }
            
        // close the socket
        close(sockfd);
    }
    
        enter code here
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Kindly post all relevant code here instead of providing external links.

Comment: it s more then one file thats why. and its too long

Comment: If you can read a file, and if you can even a single byte over a socket from you program, then you can send a file as well. And "multiple" files only means that you have to do it multiple times (like in a loop?)

Comment: yes  i try send 2 file  and for some reason he can t send the first file exactly he stop receive  file and block before eof marke in the first file ,

Comment: Try to create a [mre] by removing code that is not necessary to reproduce the problem, step by step. For example, you could remove code for progress bar or directory listing. If the reduced code does no longer show the problem, the the error might be in the removed code. To find out where your program crashes, build a debug version by using `gcc`'s option `-g` and run it in a debugger. Add sanitizer options `-fsanitize=address -fsanitize=undefined`. See also https://airbus-seclab.github.io/c-compiler-security/

Comment: First of all, why do you pass the socket file descriptor using a *pointer*? That makes no sense. Secondly, in the `share_msg` function you do `read(*sockfd, msg, sizeof(msg))` *twice`... Why? And thirdly, you fail to check for errors in many cases.

Comment: Failure to correctly and completely handle the results returned by system calls like read().  Failure to correctly handle the byte-streaming nature of TCP.

Comment: Oh.... and failure to guarantee NUL-termination of char arrays passed to library calls that require them.  I thought at first that you had avoided that member of the trifecta, but no:(

Comment: it s my first time with socket take it easy gays  talk in english  i can t understand you @martin james please explain